# How can I restore my default .bashrc file again?

Tags: bash, files, linux-mint, deleted-files

I accidentally changed all the contents of the `.bashrc` file and I haven't scripted it yet so there's no problem for now. I added little scripts to it (just a few `alias`), so I can write them again one by one.

How can I restore my .bashrc file with the default settings?

I use Linux Mint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> There exist backup copies of .bashrc, .profile etc. in /etc/skel/. So one could replace a corrupt .bashrc simply by overwitting from there.

[How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default)

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a default `bashrc` file you can restore:

`cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~` (equivalent of `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/<user>`)

Answer (score 5):

The original file that is used when every home directory is created is located in:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

The easiest way:

```
cat /etc/skel/.bashrc > ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Why `cat` instead of `cp`?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It doesn't matter. If one want's to copy the file, then that works as well. Using `cat` and `>` to redirect the output the `~/.bashrc` does the exact same thing. It's just the first thing that came to mind. One could ask the inverse for the other method but the same would be true.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson file ownership?

Comment: @RonJohn Whether a file or directory,the ownership of data will remain the same with either method. One of the ways that it wouldn't is with `rsync` and even with that, there are switches that can be used to prevent it.

Answer (score 4):

To all of the answers that say `/etc/skel/.bashrc` -

(and similarly when `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is not the final answer

eg when an IT department administering engineering workstations makes slightly different changes depending on role such as RTL table designer or verification engineer

- approaches such as `create a new account`, and snarf its `.bashrc` and other default files)

Add "VERSION CONTROL YOUR HOME DIRECTORY", or at least your rc files.

If you make any significant changes to them.